# Need help in MySQL query - GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I need help in creating a query for my database.

I have 2 tables,

**asset** which consists of (hostname, owner, engineer, date, branch)

**branch** which consists of (id, name, address, region)

branch.id is a primary key which is connected to asset.branch which is obviously a foreign key.

I wanted to create a query that displays the branch information (id, name, address, region) and the number of assets in that branch.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.address, b.xcor, b.ycor, b.status, 
  COUNT(a.hostname) AS noofasset
FROM branch b, asset a 
WHERE a.branch = b.id
GROUP BY b.id;
```

It worked at a glance, but failed to display branch information that has no assets in it.
I need a query that also displays branches that have 0 asset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.address, b.xcor, b.ycor, b.status, 
  COUNT(a.hostname) AS noofasset
FROM branch b
LEFT JOIN  asset a 
  on a.branch = b.id
GROUP BY b.id, b.name, b.address, b.xcor, b.ycor, b.status
```

LEFT join says include all branches regardless if an asset exists.

This [site](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) explains left, right outer full and types of joins visually.. I liked it :D

Using the syntax you're more familiar with  (I think)

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.address, b.xcor, b.ycor, b.status, 
  COUNT(a.hostname) AS noofasset
FROM branch b, asset a 
WHERE a.branch(+) = b.id
GROUP BY b.id;
```

Comment: wow that works really welL!!! I'm not familiar with JOINs, so I'll definitely check out the website :D

Comment: thanks for giving me another solution. What do you mean by (+)?

Comment: (+) is the non-ansi standard way of joinging. Prior to 1987 the only  way to do a join in most databases was to use the 2nd approach.  after 87 the INNER, left, full outer and cross joins became a standard.  The two should give you equivalent results. think of the (+) as meaning  ... (oops I have them backwards (and will correct)) if a corresponding record doesn't exist in my asset table, return the branch anyway.

Comment: The `(+)` notation was Oracle specific, to my knowledge.

Comment: I know some used * = or = * others used (+)= or =(+) still others used += or =+  just depends on the version, engine Manufacturer etc...